# What does this SELECT statement do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I am looking at some code and came across something extremely unfamiliar to me ; Google did not prove fruitful for results so I was wondering if anyone could explain what the following code does? It does not refer to any of my tables or databases, so I assume it's general code and I needn't provide my database layout? Thanks very much.

The code :

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Object_ID) AS weeks 
                FROM    SYS.OBJECTS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will select the numbers from 1 to N where N is the number of rows in sys.objects. It will not guarantee a sort-order.

Probably this code is intended to provide all week numbers (omg!) under the assumption that there are at least 52 rows in sys.objects.

This code, however, will return more than 52 rows and the result is not guaranteed to be ordered. I recommend you get rid of this nastiness.

Edit: As an alternative, I'd choose to create the following table: `CREATE TABLE Weeks (WeekNumber TINYINT NOT NULL PrimaryKey)` and fill it appropriately. This will be even faster than selecting from sys.objects because this custom table will be smaller and correctly sorted.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Can you suggest an alternative piece of code that would do equivalent to this, but where you can set the number of rows ?

Comment: I have added my alternative. As a bonus, you can use this table to store additional per-week data.

Answer (score 0):

The developer is using records in the system table `sysobjects` to get a list of sequential numbers by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and aliasing the column as "Weeks".  The number of rows in the `sys.objects` view will change based on the objects defined to the database so why someone would do this is beyond me...

If a simple list of sequential numbers is needed there are more predictable ways to get them.

Comment: The numbers are not even guaranteed to be sequential. When there are a lot of rows a parallel plan will kick in and disturb ordering.

Comment: you can be quite sure there is more than 53 objects in sysobjects, so you got all the weeks of the year covered. And yes, they will be sequential numbered but maybe not selected. Kind of depends of the "order by" in the select statement

Comment: I should let this go, but...  @usr, are you saying that ROW_NUMBER() OVER (any primary key field) could result in result in non-unique row number results?  I think not.

Comment: It will result in unique row numbers, but their ordering might not be sequential. Only the order-by-clause at the very end of the query guarantees ordering. The one in the over clause does not. For example you can use different orderings in two different over-clauses. If you still think that it would be ok to put such code into production because "it works on my machine" please do not come near my codebase ;-)

Comment: @usr: If you actually had read my answer you will clearly see that I do not condone this method of generating week numbers.  Thanks for the attitude.